# my application in google play console is still in the "under checking" state

Tags: android, google-play-console, google-developers-console

I added my app to the play store on October 4th. Nothing has happened since then. Until now, all of my previous applications have been published within 2-4 days of them being uploaded.

Should I do anything else?
[Picture of my Google play console dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYDeQ.png)

Comment: Give it more time? Could be that your application requires a more thorough review.

Answer (score 0):

Just wait a bit longer:

> Certain apps may be subject to extended reviews, which may result in review times of up to 7 days or longer in exceptional cases.

([source](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859751?hl=en))

Answer (score 0):

Same situation. I've been waiting since 2 Oct. When I contact Google it says it may take 7 days or longer. They do not have a solution-oriented approach. There is nothing we should do but wait. It was also said that the waiting period will start all over again in a new update.